# How to use dynamic root path in nginx based on $uri?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am hosting multiple django apps in one server.

When the user visits : http://dev-app.example.com/testapp1

I need to serve /static with a root path dynamically generated from the $uri, because I am not using the same assets across the apps but the same path to them.

My nginx config files tree :

```
nginx
├── sites-enabled
│   ├── myconf
│   myapps/
│   ├── testapp1
│   └── testapp2
```

myconf file :

```
server {
    listen 8088;
    server_name dev-app.example.com;

    location = favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static 
        # The line below isn't working even if the $uri has the string I want to concatenate
        root /home/user$uri/current;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/myapps/*;
}
```

testapp1 file :

```
location /testapp1 {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user/testapp1/current/testapp1.sock;
}
```

testapp2 file :

```
location /testapp2 {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user/testapp2/current/testapp2.sock;
}
```

I want to use nginx built-in variable $uri to build my root path for /static location in `myconf` file for each requested app accordingly.

When the user opens http://dev-app.example.com/whatever I want to serve this :

```
# In the myconf file
location /static {
     root /home/user/whatever/current;
}
```

Comment: Can you show bigger piece of your nginx config? I can't understand how this should work...

Comment: @GwynBleidD I just did, thanks.

Comment: Just checking if understood correctly, your apps are served on `//yourdomain.com/testapp1` and `//yourdomain.com/testapp2`, but for both apps your static files are located in `//yourdomain.com/static`. Correct?

Comment: @GwynBleidD Yes, the static files must be in //yourdomain.com/static so each app can have its assets. /static will be always the location of the static files in both testapp1 and testapp2, but to which root path /static redirects to is what changes accordingly to the request of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work that way.

First, you have to understand how HTTP requests work. Each request, either for your website or for static files is separate and it have it's own URL. Nginx can't pair by itself request for static file to request for website from which that static file was requested...

The only way that nginx may know that is `Referer` header, that browser can send with request to static file. This may contain path to web document from which static file was requested, but it also can be empty! It also can just contain path to root of your website.

Also, browsers will try to cache everything they can, so if user visits `http://example.com/testapp1` and that site contains reference for `http://example.com/static/style.css`, browser will cache it and on request to `http://example.com/testapp2` browser won't download new css file, but will rather use cached one.

If you're sure that your web clients will always send proper `Referer` header and won't cache any static files, you may try to extract path to app from `$http_referer` variable in nginx.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, so there is no way to host multiple apps in one server block?

Comment: Yes, there is! But not that way. Just create separate static paths for each app. Check `STATIC_URL` setting in django for that.

Comment: Ok thanks. Actually I need to keep /static for some reasons. I ended up using sub-subdomain (testapp1.dev-app.example.com) - capturing the first part (testapp1) and then using an if statement in the nginx conf.

Answer (score 0):

Set the static location inside each server block

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name pool.simlabdevelopments.com; 
  root /srv/http/simlabdevelopments.com;

  location /static/ {
    alias   /srv/webapps/autopool/static/;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have only one server block, and I want to make the alias/root dynamic based on $uri.